# Vue CLI Project doesnt Hot Reload after yarn -> npm switch. No config files either?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, vue-cli

Due to clients/coworkers wish I have to switch to npm. The Project was created using Vue CLI and Yarn as default Package Manager.

I first thought no big deal, so I deleted node_modules folder and yarn.lock file. Then I ran `npm install` and then `npm run serve`.

It works and compiles like normal, recompiles when I change a file, all good so far but here is the weird part: the changes do not reflect in the browser. I have to refresh the page manually.

I tried to look into config files for vue or webpack. But there are none. No Webpack config, no vue cli config, no build folder.

What I have is:
- .eslintrc.js
- .browserlistrc
- babel.config.js
- postcss.config.js

I dont know what else to look for? Anyone any idea what this might be?

Thanks a lot,
-J

Comment: Do you have `react-scripts` as dependency in your `package.json`, or maybe any other bundling "simplifier"?

Comment: no, I dont have react dependencies in my `package.json`, I havent added any devDependencies myself.

Answer (score 0):

### What was the cause in my case(I have Linux OS):

It seems that the value of: `max_user_watches`
in the `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
is affecting webpack => which is interfering with hot reloading.

To check your actual value

```
$cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
16384
```

16384 was in my case and it still wasn't enough.
So you will need to increase your value as well.

### SOLUTION if you have Linux OS:

Create the file:

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/90-override.conf`

And populate it with:

`fs.inotify.max_user_watches=200000`

It seems 200000 is enough for me, you can have a higher value if you want.

After you create the file and add the value, just restart the PC and you should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Vue CLI depends on `@vue/cli-service` which acts exactly like Facebook's Create React App (`react-scripts`).

> If you are familiar with create-react-app, @vue/cli-service is roughly
>   the equivalent of react-scripts, although the feature set is
>   different.
>
> https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/#cli-service

So what both of them do is "simplify" configuration of the project for you by hiding all the bundling configs (e.g. `webpack.config.js`) under the carpet. Which is handy in most cases, unless you decide to do something fancy (like switch package manager). In Create React App one can bail out from this behavior by running `yarn eject` or `npm run eject`, but on Vue CLI platform you are locked in. So there's no straightforward way to make all underlying config files to appear and fix the faulty bits in them.

To be contunued?..

Comment: sorry. not trying to be rude, but how is this relevant for what I am trying to do? Did you read my question?

Comment: Ehm... wrote a meaningful placeholder, while searching for real answer. But it's true nevertheless.

Comment: in my eyes, when using npm I will commit package-lock.json and not yarn.lock - so why commit it and not delete it? Doesnt make sense to me. And has nothing to do with the hot reload. The project works like a charm just developing without hot reload is pretty annoying. Thanks for your help.

Comment: They are not equivalent (at least they weren't) `yarn.lock` having a less "prone to errors" format.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I have tried to create a new project using Vue CLI with npm as default package manager, then copied over all the src files and added the dependencies manually to package.json. No luck same result, no hot reloading :(

Comment: Woa... now that's weird.

Comment: Try to append `--host localhost` to the `serve` command in your `package.json` and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: didnt say they are equivalent. Just under the impression that npm wont use yarn.lock, so why not delete it? When I rebuild from github and use yarn again it works again. But somehow need to figure out how to get npm to work with hot reloading

Comment: `--host localhost` added, but still no hot reloading :(

Comment: See, yarn is better :D

Comment: OHH and I just noticed that vue DevTools Plugin says `Vue.js not detected` thats super weird.

Comment: It should be served somewhat differently then, maybe on a different port? And DevTools not recognizing/blocking it because of that?

Comment: hmm I dont know when I use npm run serve the project is not detected as vue project by the devtool plugin... thats probably why the hot reload isnt working. Something in the config breaks when using npm instead of yarn.

Comment: Why does it even matter to whoever told you to not use `yarn`, what are you using locally on your workstation. As far as you have that `yarn.lock` deleted? :D Otherwise let them solve this riddle and enjoy their suffering.

Comment: because they use npm in all their projects and are integrating my library into their workflow they asked me to switch to npm. This warning saying that we shouldnt mix and match different package managers and having it their way is the reason I guess.

Comment: I tried your steps exactly and it works here perfectly :/